# Images lose their transparence on DialogActivity

Tags: android, dialog, imageview, transparency

I have an XML layout, which has 3 different images (PNG). In Ecpilse I see all collectly. In the manifest I decleared the activity as `android:theme="@style/Theme.Dialog.NoTitleBar"` but when I run it on the phone, the three images have lost their transparency, the background is white...

I have no idea. I'm not doing anything via code. 
What could the problem be?

Here the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/azure" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/search_image_back_arrov"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/test" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search_image_back_arrov"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/fc_europ_logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@drawable/template_background"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_edittext_input"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/search_search_img_container"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/search_movie" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/search_search_img_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/search"
                    android:src="@drawable/lupe" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Dialog is created as an activity followings:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    }

}
```

Here the pictures:

[image] [image]

Comment: How are you creating the dialog?

Comment: Since i have decleared it in the manifest....as an activity. I added the code.

Comment: Are you sure? take a look to the RelativeLayout...

Comment: I added the screenshots

Answer (score -1):

try add the following code : dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); or instaead - try to clean your project and run it again.
clean project : project > clean.